# v.clean batch process within QGIS 2.10 (PISA)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, batch

I get an error message when I try to create a batch for v.clean operation..

`Algorithm v.clean - Toolset for cleaning topology of vector map. starting...
local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment See log for more details`

And I don't really get why...
Here a screenshot of my setting:

[image: v.clean batch setting]